# Reading .txt. data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a very basic table

```
Alcohol  Tobacco
6.47    4.03
6.13    3.76
6.19    3.77
4.89    3.34
5.63    3.47
4.52    2.92
5.89    3.20
4.79    2.71
5.27    3.53
6.08    4.51
4.02    4.56
```

I have tried reading it in using textscan but get blank.

```
fileID = fopen('TabaccoAlcohol.txt');
C_text = textscan(fileID,'%n',2);
```

It would be nice in the program using the headings as objects, e.g. Alcohol would be all 11 rows of data. I know Matlab can do this but I can't make it work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code with this code is given below

```
fileID = fopen('read.txt');
C_text = textscan(fileID,' %f %f');
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: It is still empty. The columns are seperated by tab, does that make a difference?

Comment: Ok. I've cheated. I have manually removed the tab and made a space instead so now it works.

Comment: This works fine for me. The another method is "load" command. Just use this command: load TabaccoAlcohol.txt

Answer (score 1):

Use [readtable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html):

```
>> t = readtable('data.txt')

t = 

    Alcohol    Tobacco
    _______    _______

    6.47       4.03   
    6.13       3.76   
    6.19       3.77   
    4.89       3.34   
    5.63       3.47   
    4.52       2.92   
    5.89        3.2   
    4.79       2.71   
    5.27       3.53   
    6.08       4.51   
    4.02       4.56  

>> t.Alcohol

ans =

    6.4700
    6.1300
    6.1900
    4.8900
    5.6300
    4.5200
    5.8900
    4.7900
    5.2700
    6.0800
    4.0200
```